# Issue in contact form

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am trying to create a simple form using Javascript, but I am facing an issue while trying to display somethings on the console. The issue here is that whenever I click on the submit button, Nothing is displayed on the console despite giving the command `e.preventdefault()`. At present I want the text Hello to be displayed on console when it satisfies the condition, but even though the condition is satisfied, nothing is displayed.

Herewith attaching the Javascript and HTML code for the same

```js
const passlength = 10;
const firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
const lastname = document.getElementById("lastname");
const emailid = document.getElementById("emailid");
const password = document.getElementById("pass");
const confirmpassword = document.getElementById("passconfirm");
const phonenumber = document.getElementById("phno");
const form = document.querySelector(".mainform");


function testfunc() {
    console.log(type(emailid));
}

function checkpass(pass) {
    if (pass>=passlength) {
        console.log("Hello");
    }
    else{
        console.log("Out");
    }
}

form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    checkpass(password);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register with us</title>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="mainform">

        <form>
            <label for="firstname">First name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
            <label for="lastname">Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br>
            <label for="emailid">Email ID:</label>
            <input type="email" id="emailid" name="emailid"><br>

            <label for="pass">Enter password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass"> <br>
            <label for="passconfirm">Confirm password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="passconfirm" name="passconfirm"> <br>
            <label for="phno">Phone number:</label>
            <input type="number" id="phno" name="phno">

            <br> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form>


    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just use    `checkpass(password.value.length);` You need to get value of input and its length to compere it

Comment: Where do you include the script in the HTML? for me its working fine, but as ikiK Stated, you need the length of the password, and not the string itself when checking for length.

Comment: yes I figured out that I haven't linked my JS file to the HTML

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your If statement. You are comparing a number with an HTML element. You still need these two.

`.value` returns the value of the html element
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

`.length` returns the length of a string
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

This is how you compare two numbers, as you intended.
So your new IF condition must be:

```js
(pass.value.length>=passlength)
```

Comment: yes I corrected that by passing the value of the element to that function and now it works. Thank you for the help